# How to get application port programmatically in Dropwizard

Tags: dropwizard

I am using dropwizard version 0.7.1. It is configured to use "random" (ephemeral?) port (server.applicationConnectors.port=0). I want to get what port is really in use after startup, but I can't find any information how to do that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get a `serverStarted` callback from a lifecycle listener to figure this out.

```java
@Override
public void run(ExampleConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
  environment.lifecycle().addServerLifecycleListener(new ServerLifecycleListener() {
    @Override
    public void serverStarted(Server server) {
      for (Connector connector : server.getConnectors()) {
        if (connector instanceof ServerConnector) {
          ServerConnector serverConnector = (ServerConnector) connector;
          System.out.println(serverConnector.getName() + " " + serverConnector.getLocalPort());
          // Do something useful with serverConnector.getLocalPort()
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Since Dropwizard 1.1.0, ServerLifecycleListener provides a `getLocalPort()` convenience method, see [this commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25542050/how-to-get-application-port-programmatically-in-dropwizard).

Answer (score 3):

I find this approach worked well for me with both the Simple and Default server configurations in Dropwizard.

```java
public void run(ExampleConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {

    Stream<ConnectorFactory> connectors = configuration.getServerFactory() instanceof DefaultServerFactory
            ? ((DefaultServerFactory)configuration.getServerFactory()).getApplicationConnectors().stream()
            : Stream.of((SimpleServerFactory)configuration.getServerFactory()).map(SimpleServerFactory::getConnector);

    int port = connectors.filter(connector -> connector.getClass().isAssignableFrom(HttpConnectorFactory.class))
            .map(connector -> (HttpConnectorFactory) connector)
            .mapToInt(HttpConnectorFactory::getPort)
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);
}
```

Comment: Works :) and also I didn't undetstand @condit's solution to get local port. Didn't get any method to call getLocalPort().